# I want replace pattern that is matched

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am trying to replace string that is matched 
see example bellow

```
<?php
    $str="this is going to bold [[this]]";
    echo preg_replace("/[[(.*)]]+/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
?>
```

So the output will look like this

this is going to bold  **this**

**Edit:**

```
<?php
    $str="bhai bhai *that* -wow- perfect";
    $find[0]="/*(.+)*/i";
    $find[1]="/-(.+)-/i";
    $rep[0]="<b>$1</b>";
    $rep[1]="<i>$1</i>";
    echo preg_replace($find,$rep,$str);
?>
```

This is showing warning

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\page.php on line 7

Comment: `[]` are special characters in PCRE and thus must be escaped.  Also, you might want to use a non-greedy group.  `(.*?)` otherwise you're going to run into some fun bolding issues down the road.

Comment: i changed to this ...echo preg_replace("/\[\[+(.*)+\]\]/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);....but i am seeing this output..........this is going to bold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
    $str="this is going to bold [[this]]";
    echo preg_replace("/\[\[(.+)\]\]+/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
?>
```

**Output :**

> this is going to bold **this**

---

**Hint :**

`[` and `]` characters are considered *special*, so you'll have to escape them (like : `\[`, `\]`).

---

**UPDATE :**

---

```
<?php
    $str="bhai bhai *that* -wow- perfect";
    $find[0]="/\*(.+)\*/i";
    $find[1]="/\-(.+)\-/i";
    $rep[0]="<b>$1</b>";
    $rep[1]="<i>$1</i>";
    echo preg_replace($find,$rep,$str);
?>
```

Comment: what is difference between (.+) and (.*) ?

Comment: @user1331534 `+` indicates that the pattern is to be matched ONE-or-more times, while `*` indicates that it is to be matched ZERO-or-more times (which means that it may not match anything).

Comment: @user1331534 **Example *(from Wikipedia)* :** `ab*c` matches "ac", "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on. `ab+c` matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on, but not "ac"

Comment: on question i want to improve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size

```
<?php
    $str="this is going to bold [[this]]";
    echo preg_replace("/(?:\[\[)(.*?)(?:\]\])/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the square brackets in your regular expression. The final expression should look something like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/im', '<b>$1</b>', $str);
```

The square brackets are special characters used for defining a set of characters and thus must be escaped if you wish to match them literally.